# Unable to find an OpenAPI description

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, webapi

I am working the Microsoft Learn tutorials to "Create a web API with ASP.Net Core".

I used .NET5

I have a problem when I run the command:

```
httprepl connect http://localhost:5000
```

I am getting a response, "Unable to find an OpenAPI description".

And the following command "ls" returns me from it not trooping endpoints.

```
c:/xxx/Source/Repos/ContosoPizza
$ httprepl http://localhost:5000
(Disconnected)> connect http://localhost:5000
Using a base address of http://localhost:5000/
Unable to find an OpenAPI description
For detailed tool info, see https://aka.ms/http-repl-doc

http://localhost:5000/> ls
No directory structure has been set, so there is nothing to list. Use the "connect" command to set a directory structure based on an OpenAPI description.
```

I tried all the solutions offered by @Gowiser in the question launched by @Nuse [Why is HttpRepl unable to find an OpenAPI description? The command "ls" does not show available endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278068/why-is-httprepl-unable-to-find-an-openapi-description-the-command-ls-does-not)

But nothing worked.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You said you tried everything suggested in the linked Q&A, but how exactly did you try it? What's your code to add and use Swagger in your `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 3):

Working through [Create a web API with ASP.NET Core Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/) i also did run into the error

> Unable to find an OpenAPI description

The tutorial uses dotnet 6, i was using dotnet core 3.1.

I did the changes [from sasha answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699771/819887) and had to add these packages

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.OpenApi --version 1.2.3 
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger --version 6.2.3 
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI --version 6.2.3 
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen --version 6.2.3
```

After all that i still got error messages. In step 4 of [Exercise - Create a web API project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/3-exercise-create-web-api) the following is written

> Connect to our web API by running the following command:
>
> ```
> httprepl https://localhost:{PORT}
> ```
>
> Alternatively, run the following command at any time while the HttpRepl is running:
>
> ```
> (Disconnected)> connect https://localhost:{PORT}
> ```

I was not aware that running `httprepl` like this

```
httprepl https://localhost:{PORT}
```

still requires that your web app is running. So you have to open a second terminal (cmd.exe) to run your webapi project `dotnet run`. After that you can connect to the swagger docs using httprepl like this

```
connect http://localhost:5000 --verbose --openapi /swagger/v1/swagger.json

http://localhost:5000/> ls                           
.                 []
WeatherForecast   [GET]

http://localhost:5000/> cd WeatherForecast
/WeatherForecast    [GET]

http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast> get
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

This did the trick for me.

### Adding the swagger ui

[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore - Getting Started](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#getting-started) contains

> Optionally, insert the swagger-ui middleware if you want to expose
> interactive documentation, specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint(s) to
> power it from.
>
> ```
> app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
> {
>     c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
> });
> ```

If you change `startup.cs` to include this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ContosoPizza v1"));
    }            
    ....
```

You get a nice gui under `http://localhost:5000/swagger/` which looks like this

[image: Swagger ui]

Comment: Wow. So it does! Works great. The MS tutorial had the UseSwagger() methods commented out (don't know why). Un-commenting them and doing the URL above revealed a nice Postman like view of the project. I didn't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are following the steps described in the ['Create a web API project' exercise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/3-exercise-create-web-api) of the [Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/) course.

Before going through step 5. make sure in your project there is:

- a `services.AddSwaggerGen()` call in the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method
- an `app.UseSwagger()` call in the `Startup.Configure()` method

Here is a working version of Startup.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace ContosoPizza
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ContosoPizza", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ContosoPizza v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `ls` in the `httprepl` session shows expected results:

```
❯ httprepl http://localhost:5000
(Disconnected)> connect http://localhost:5000
Using a base address of http://localhost:5000/
Using OpenAPI description at http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json
For detailed tool info, see https://aka.ms/http-repl-doc

http://localhost:5000/> ls
.                 []
WeatherForecast   [GET]

http://localhost:5000/>
```

[Here you can find](https://github.com/ferrata/build-web-api-aspnet-core/tree/main/3-exercise-create-web-api) a full project for this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed @surfmuggle to connect to the API via `httprepl`, the API had to be running in another terminal, so 2 terminals in total:

- 1 to run the API with `dotnet run`
- 1 other to call instructions like `ls` or other later

Answer (score -1):

run this command first:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).