# SSL Certificate problems when trying to use httprepl on ASP.NET tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, ssl, ubuntu-18.04

I'm new to C# and .NET and I'm trying to follow [the "Create a web API" tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-model-class) on the Microsoft site. At the [Test PostTodoItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#test-posttodoitem) section, I followed the instructions to install `httprepl` and tried to execute the following two commands:

```
httprepl https://localhost:5001/api/todoitems
post -h Content-Type=application/json -c "{"name":"walk dog","isComplete":true}"
```

I get the following error in my terminal: `The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`. Screengrab:
[image]

I've tried to follow various instructions to update the SSL certificates on my machine. For example, when I type  `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` I get the following:,
[image: screenshot of response to dotnet dev-certs https --trust]

The `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.` response would suggest that I've fixed the issue, but I still can't get `httprepl` to run correctly. I've tried it on a Windows machine and it works fine (they have a much simpler way of handling SSL requests/granting permissions).

I can run the app/API in my browser, so I don't think I need to make any changes where Firefox/Chrome are concerned?

I've looked at other [stack overflow solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278068/why-is-httprepl-unable-to-find-an-openapi-description-the-command-ls-does-not) and they either don't work or I don't understand them. My `dotnet --version` is `6.0.101`.

I'm pretty sure I've created SSL certificates for this already. I have a file called `https.crt` in my `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet` folder:
[image: screenshot of https.crt]

I don't know if it's relevant, but it has "DNS: localhost' there at the bottom. Can anyone explain how to troubleshoot/resolve this so I can get the tutorial working? I tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59702094/11664580) but I was unable to copy the `localhost.crt` into my `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` folder. I compared the `localhost.crt` with my existing `https.crt` and it looked nearly identical, so I guessed it wouldn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround that works just as well as httprepl (but without this problem). You can use VSCode "Rest Client" extension to run http requests described in .http files. It automatically configures CA certificate. The "HTTP Client" plugin of Jetbrains Rider works the same way.

Comment: Great work Danil. Glad you figured it out!